# Why isnt my Ajax call progressing past readystate 1?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I feel like I've done everything right, but I get no response from my Ajax call, what am I missing?

```
function loadMedia() {

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon', true);
console.log(xhr.readyState);

xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200 ) {
        console.log(true)
        let txt = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(txt)
        for(let i in txt) {
            console.log(txt[i])
        }
    }
}
console.log(xhr.readyState)
xhr.send()
}
```

It just stays at readystate 1.

Comment: Asynchronous vs synchronous.  You are creating the XHR and starting it, then logging the ready state twice before the XHR has had an opportunity to do anything.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Btw, this is a pretty old way of doing things.  Fetch API is the way to go now.

Answer (score 0):

`xhr.readyState` will not help you in the way that you wrote the code, you have to debug whether or not `onload` is called.

```
console.log(xhr.readyState); // sync
xhr.onload = function() {
   // async inside the function call, when onload
}; 
console.log(xhr.readyState) // sync, this isn't waiting AJAX response
```

If you put `console.log(xhr.readyState)` inside your callback fn it'll log other values, but remember to handle `onerror` as well...

I'd suggest you to use `addEventListener` listeners API instead of old fashion event handlers.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would suggest using `onreadystatechange` as the event to listen to. It specifically monitors the change in that property value.

Comment: yeah, but the question here is why to observe the state change? it seems like he followed some old article... addEventListener('load') is what you need